# jQuery - Get this/element within filter()

Tags: jquery, filter

Using benpickles `onSCreen` plugin (https://benpickles.github.io/onScreen/) I am using the following piece of code to try and change the image src of all elements with jQuery's `filter()` method on any images that are visisble on screen.

```
<img class="img-d" src="old-image-23.jpg" data-src="new-image-37.jpg"/>
<img class="img-d" src="old-image-54.jpg" data-src="new-image-7.jpg"/>
<img class="img-d" src="old-image-12.jpg" data-src="new-image-98.jpg"/>


jQuery(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    jQuery('.img-d')
        .filter(":onScreen")
        .attr('src', jQuery(this).data('src'))
  }, 
  1000)
});
```

However `jQuery(this)` is not working when I try and change the img src.

Can anyone help?

Comment: why not use `$` instead of jQuery?

Comment: @N.Ivanov you can use jQuery instead of $ there is no issue for that both returns same instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `attr()` with a callback to access each element and return the data-attributes value

```
jQuery(function($) {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.img-d').filter(":onScreen").attr('src', function() {
        return $(this).data('src');
    });
  }, 1000)
});
```

Note how the function closes over `$` so you don't have to type `jQuery` every time.
Why you would do this every second, is beyond me though?